# Get data from itunes rss feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, command-line

What is the use of [i] in below program Xcode?

```
for (unsigned short int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Top iOS Apps %i in App store is  - %@  released on - %@",i,appStore100Apps[@"feed"][@"results"][i][@"name"],appStore100Apps[@"feed"][@"results"][i][@"releaseDate"]); 
}
```

Comment: That's to access the element at index i in the array (Indexed Subscripting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop goes through the first 100 elements in the array, and `i` acts as the counter when iterating through the loop, and accesses the `i`th result in the app store feed specifically via index subscripting on the array of `results`

Answer (score 0):

`[i]` will increase when the loop goes. It will get each record of `appStore100Apps` until it hits 100.